# How to create a dictionary of dictionaries using 3 lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have 3 lists. The first list contains 2 values. The second list contains multiple values including some repeating however they only repeat when they match the same position as a different value from list 1. Then the 3rd list which contains unique values for every item.

```
list_1 = ["Value1", "Value1", "Value2", "value1"]
list_2 = ["1111", "1234", "1111", "2468"]
list_3 = ["uniqueValue1", "uniqueValue2", "uniqueValue3", "uniqueValue4"]
```

I want to create 1 dictionary that has value1 and value 2 as the key, then the other 2 lists to be dictionaries inside based on the position they are in the list.

```
AllData = {"Value1": "Value1Dict", "Value2": "Value2Dict"}
Value1Dict = {"1111": "uniqueValue1", "1234": "uniqueValue2", "2468": "uniqueValue4"}
Value2Dict = {"1111": "UniqueValue3"}
```

So essentially I have ordered data that matches the position of Value1 and Value 2 but I need to separate it. If there is an easier way to do this then I'm also game for trying out that suggestion too.

Comment: Not sure if the example dictionaries just isn't 100% what you want them to be or if I missunderstand your example output. But wouldn't it be better to nest the dictionaries into one? `{'Value1' : {1111 : 'UniqueValue1', 1234 : 'UniqueValue2'}}` for instance?

Comment: Yes sorry, you are correct. I will edit my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for but note the order of your nested dictionaries might not be identical to the original `list_2` and `list_3` values.

```
In [20]: x = {k: {} for k in list_1}

In [21]: for a, b, c in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
    ...:     x[a][b] = c
    ...:     

In [22]: x
Out[22]: 
{'Value1': {'1111': 'uniqueValue1',
  '1234': 'uniqueValue2',
  '2468': 'uniqueValue4'},
 'Value2': {'1111': 'uniqueValue3'}}
```

Comment: Great thanks, that seems to work and also seems to be in the correct order that I was after. Why might the order not be identical all the time? Edit: On further investigation I see you mean the order in which the pairs appear. This is fine, the importance is that the correct pairs are matched up.

Comment: Normal dictionaries do not store the order of the data. Check@Batman's answer below if order is important.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_data = defaultdict(dict)
for outer_key, inner_key, value in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
    all_data[outer_key][inner_key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you virtually have the answer above. You could just nest the dictionaries in the following way

```
Value1Dict = {"1111": "uniqueValue1", "1234": "uniqueValue2", "2468": "uniqueValue4"}
Value2Dict = {"1111": "UniqueValue3"}
AllData = {"Value1": Value1Dict, "Value2": Value2Dict}
```

That should nest the dictionaries correctly!

Comment: I should add that I have hundreds of items in each list and therefore need a way to do it without actually writing out each value myself.